# Losing accuracy as thread speed increases

Tags: java

So i have this simple thread that updates my TextBox with the new time difference every second.

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    editTextBox.setText(""+timeDifference);
```

But I want the TextBox to update faster, yet maintain the same value. So my idea was to reduce the sleep value to 1/4 of what it is now (250), and to keep my output the same I would also cut my output by 1/4, resulting in this:

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(250);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    editTextBox.setText(""+timeDifference/4);
```

However the 2nd examples output is about 10% behind. Why is this? Does the computation of my processes take longer than 250ms and that's why its behind?

thanks in advance

Comment: You should multiply `timeDifference` by four, not divide...

Comment: Where is `timeDifference` coming from?

Comment: what is `timeDifference` value? And is it `int` or `double`?

Comment: are you 100% sure, thread speed is the only cause of losing accuracy....? And could you show complete code here?

Comment: timeDifference is computed each cycle and added to the total with: timeDifference += ((actualSpeedMph/selectedSpeed) - 1);. The total is accurate when run every 1000ms but falls behind when run at 250ms and timeDifference is divided by 4.

Answer (score 4):

`Thread.sleep(250)` does not mean that your thread will begin executing again **exactly** 250 ms later.

When you sleep a thread, its state passes to `idle`. When the `sleep` ends, it passes to `active`, which means that can be executed, but the scheduler may be busy executing another thread (or even chose other thread for execution before that.

Add to that the time needed to put back into execution a thread (change of environment) and and possible timing errors, and you have an delay. Most of that variation, while not constant, is not related to the time spent sleeping, so the difference is comparatively bigger when the sleep time is small.

In the end, remember that `Java` is not a Real Time System and so you cannot expect times to follow a close "schedule" (for want of a better word).

Answer (score 3):

It really doesn't matter what the problem with this program is, because you shouldn't invoke any methods on a Swing UI component from a thread other than [the Event Dispatch Thread.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Instead, the timer thread should be periodically passing a task to [`invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29). That task should quickly compute the time to be displayed and set the text property of the text box.

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
  private long previous = System.currentTimeMillis();
  @Override
  public void run() {
    editTextBox.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - previous));
  }
};
while (true) {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(250);
  }
  catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    break;
  }
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(task);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but my project dosen'tt recognize the import javax.swing.SwingUtilities; and im having trouble installing the latest jdk with IntelliJ