# Increacing the speed of thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

After every call of thread it's speed is increased (specifically - FirstCircleRepaintThread, SecoundCircleRepaintThread, LineRepaintThread). But the main thread's speed is normal. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116344/losing-accuracy-as-thread-speed-increases) question, but my thread's speed is **always** increasing.
[GitHub](https://github.com/rberla/rest5min), [JAR on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/26iwcnbftqgh3y5/Rest5MinsV0.32_SOF.jar)
P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: OK, I'll try to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, each time you `unblock` you are creating a new instance of your threads, but you're not stopping the old ones, so they are still running, updating your UI

```
public void block() {
    setVisible(true);

    // Create a bunch of new threads...        
    firstCircleThr = new FirstCircleRepaintThread();
    firstCircleThr.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    firstCircleThr.start();
    secoundCircleThr = new SecoundCircleRepaintThread();
    secoundCircleThr.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    secoundCircleThr.start();
    lineThr = new LineRepaintThread();
    lineThr.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    lineThr.start();
}

public void unblock(){

    setVisible(false);
    // Dereference the old ones, but they are still running...        
    firstCircleThr = null;
    secoundCircleThr = null;
    lineThr = null;
    System.out.println("Yeah! OFF IT!");
}
```

For example...

```
public class FirstCircleRepaintThread extends Thread{


    public static final long SPEED_OF_ROTATING = 25L;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //while(true){

            MainCycle.frame.panel.startAngleFirst = 34;
            int i = 0;

            Random r = new Random();

            // To infinity and beyond...                
            while(true){
```

You need to supply some way you can stop these threads...without calling `stop`...

For example...

```
public class FirstCircleRepaintThread extends Thread{

    private volatile boolean keepRunning = true;

    public static final long SPEED_OF_ROTATING = 25L;

    public void kull() {

        keepRunning = false;
        interrupt();
        try {
            join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //while(true){

            MainCycle.frame.panel.startAngleFirst = 34;
            int i = 0;
            Random r = new Random();

            while(keepRunning){
```

Now in you `block` method, you should be calling `firstCircleThr.kull()`, which will stop the `Thread` before returning...

You could have seen this if you used a debugger or left the frame visible between cycles...

Now, having said all that, you're violating the single thread rules Swing, updating the state of the UI from every thread except the Event Dispatching Thread.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and consider the use of a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) or [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

You should consider maintaining as few background processes as possible in order to maintain performance and reduce the complexity of changing the model and interafce

Comment: Thank you for such a good and full answer! I'm still learning Threads , so I didn't use SwingWorker or SwingTimer, join... But I'll learn that)