# Multiple threads used to update JLabels

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel

The following code is a simple `JFrame` with a button and two `JLabels`, the objective of the code is to update the ""number `JLabel` by invoking a new Thread, instead of trying to do it in the EDT.

My problem is that the run method invokes a new thread each time you press the button, however, it does not cancel the old one. Therefore, if you press the button, and press it again a couple of seconds later you will have two threads updating the `JLabel`, and this looks crappy.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:** Every time You press the button, the counter has to start at 0, and the old thread that was updating it, has to be cancelled.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private JLabel countLabel1 = new JLabel("0");
private JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("Task not completed.");
private JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");

public MainFrame(String title) {
    super(title);

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    countLabel1.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 28));

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    add(countLabel1, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    add(statusLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    add(startButton, gc);

    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            start();
        }
    });

    setSize(200, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}


private void start() 
{
    Thread worker = new Thread() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {

            // Simulate doing something useful.
            for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {

                final int count = i;

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        countLabel1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                    }
                });

                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {

                }
            }

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() 
                {
                    statusLabel.setText("Completed.");
                }
            });

        }
    };

    worker.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame("SwingWorker Demo");
        }
    });
 }
   }
```

Comment: Instead of the for-loop in the thread, try using a while-loop that has two exit conditions, one is the count, the other is a boolean which can be set via a method call like "kull". The boolean variable would need to be volitile and you could use "join" which will wait until the thread has died before returning...for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603095/increacing-the-speed-of-thread/22603303#22603303)

Comment: Thanks so much, hahah, ive been stuck in a rut, SLEEP DEPREVATION!!! HAHA

Comment: This could also be achieved through the use of a SwingWorker, which is supports the ability to be cancelled and has easy to use functionality to resync with UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use some flag to stop previous thread as simple as it is.

One more thing that you are not updating `statusLabel` when button is clicked next time.

Try this one

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel countLabel1 = new JLabel("0");
    private JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("Task not completed.");
    private JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");

    private MyThread myThread;

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        countLabel1.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 28));

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(countLabel1, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(statusLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(startButton, gc);

        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                start();
            }
        });

        setSize(200, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void start() {
        if (myThread != null) {
            myThread.setRunning(false);
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                statusLabel.setText("Task not completed.");
            }
        });
        myThread = new MyThread(countLabel1, statusLabel);
        Thread thread = new Thread(myThread);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame("SwingWorker Demo");
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

    public MyThread(JLabel countLabel1, JLabel statusLabel) {
        this.countLabel1 = countLabel1;
        this.statusLabel = statusLabel;
    }

    private boolean running = true;
    private JLabel countLabel1, statusLabel;

    public void run() {

        // Simulate doing something useful.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

            if (running) {
                final int count = i;

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (running) {
                            countLabel1.setText(Integer.toString(count));

                            if (count == 10) {
                                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        statusLabel.setText("Completed.");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                break;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this version of your code. The main new thing is the `Updater` class which implements `Runnable`. See how it is used here. See also the changes in `private void start()`. See also the `enabled` flag in the `Updater` class.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 380931874973423432L;
    private Updater currentUpdater = null;
    private Thread currentWorker = null;
    private int cnt = 0;

    private JLabel countLabel1 = new JLabel("0");
    private JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("Initialized.");
    private JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        countLabel1.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 28));

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(countLabel1, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(statusLabel, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(startButton, gc);

        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                start();
            }
        });

        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void start() {

        cnt++;

        Thread cw = this.currentWorker;
        if (currentUpdater != null) {
            currentUpdater.setEnabled(false);
        }

        Updater newUpdater = new Updater(this, cnt);
        Thread newWorker = new Thread(newUpdater);

        try{
            if (cw!=null) 
                cw.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.currentUpdater = newUpdater;
        this.currentWorker = newWorker;

        newWorker.start();
    }

    public JLabel getCountLabel1() {
        return countLabel1;
    }

    public void setCountLabel1(JLabel countLabel1) {
        this.countLabel1 = countLabel1;
    }

    public JLabel getStatusLabel() {
        return statusLabel;
    }

    public void setStatusLabel(JLabel statusLabel) {
        this.statusLabel = statusLabel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame("SwingWorker Demo");
            }
        });
    }
}

class Updater implements Runnable {

    private int id = 0;
    private MainFrame frame = null;
    private volatile boolean enabled = false;

    public Updater(MainFrame f, int id) {
        this.frame = f;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        enabled = true;

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.getStatusLabel().setText("Task not completed. Task ID: " + id);
                System.out.println("Task not completed. Task ID: " + id);
            }
        });

        // Simulate doing something useful.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

            if (!enabled)
                break;

            final int count = i;

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    frame.getCountLabel1().setText(Integer.toString(count));
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.getStatusLabel().setText("Task completed. Task ID: " + id);
                System.out.println("Task completed. Task ID: " + id);
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 I love Runnable#Thread & invokeLater, maybe there isn't reason for joint